# Arduino Uno Constantly Resets with WiFi and 4 Relay Module

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, relay, adafruit

I am using an Arduino Uno with a 4 relay module (found here: [http://www.amazon.com/JBtek-Channel-Module-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B00KTEN3TM?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KTEN3TM)) and an Adafruit CC3000 WiFi breakout board.  However, once I connect the power source, the board just constantly cycles on and off, e.g. about 1 second per cycle.  Could this have to do with too much current being drawn? Or that the current output of the digital pins isn't enough for all of the relay inputs? I'm new with this, but I am sure all of the pins are appropriately connected.

EDIT: If I use the USB connector (5V 1A) instead of the external power supply, I can connect 1 or 2 of the relays without problem, but must do so AFTER the wifi has already connected to the network, otherwise the wifi chip will never connect.  Also, if I toggle the relays a few times, the wifi becomes unresponsive.  I suspect a current issue maybe?. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It Will be a power issue you need to supply power direct to the relay modules VCC independent of the arduino, ensure the earths are connected and just use the digital outputs from the arduino to control the relays. Digital low normally switches the corresponding relay on.